# Change value in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I have data that comes from server and i save it in NSMutableDic but when i change value in that NSMutabelDic it gives me error that i can't change in NSDic!
This is error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ae250c0'
```

This is my sample server data :

```
{
    "data": {
        "My_Tool_Box": {
            "Visual Check": [
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "1",
                    "question_id": "1",
                    "question_name": "Power leads",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "1",
                    "question_id": "2",
                    "question_name": "Power",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "1",
                    "question_id": "3",
                    "question_name": "Rcd is operational",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "1",
                    "question_id": "4",
                    "question_name": "ase to avoid damage",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "1",
                    "question_id": "5",
                    "question_name": "Safety guards if fitted  to machine ARE OPERATIONAL AND ARE NOT DAMAGED",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "1",
                    "question_id": "6",
                    "question_name": "ase to avoid damage",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "1",
                    "question_id": "7",
                    "question_name": "ase to avoid damage",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Operational checks": [
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "2",
                    "question_id": "8",
                    "question_name": "ase to avoid damage",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "2",
                    "question_id": "9",
                    "question_name": "ase to avoid damage",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "2",
                    "question_id": "10",
                    "question_name": "ase to avoid damage",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Operating instructions": [
                {
                    "que_cat_id": "3",
                    "question_id": "11",
                    "question_name": "ase to avoid damage",
                    "question_ans": "",
                    "question_ans_comments": "",
                    "question_options": {
                        "1": "Yes",
                        "2": "No",
                        "3": "N/A",
                        "4": "Comment"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Question Listing"
}
```

So i have to change value of `question_ans & question_ans_comments` so as when i change it i get error as i mention above.
This is the way i already applied:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
[newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
[newDict setObject:@"Don" forKey:@"Name"];
[dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
```

i don't have index in sequence like how i replace that key object!! Is there any easy way that i can apply here ?

This is the way i reset value :

```
[[[arrayGlobal valueForKey:[arrayAllColumn objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@"12" forKey:@"question_ans"];
```

I also tried this :

```
    NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[[arrayGlobal valueForKey:[arrayAllColumn objectAtIndex:0]] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:oldDict];
    [newDict setObject:@"12" forKey:@"question_ans"];
    [[[[arrayGlobal valueForKey:[arrayAllColumn objectAtIndex:0]] objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
```

Giving same error.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: please check again

Comment: This code works for me

Comment: code is working but in my case i have indext inside index. How can i replace is in inside index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [these categories](https://www.dropbox.com/s/obg641tnvvrobs5/Mutable%20Copy.zip?dl=0) classes and add them into your project with:

```
#import "NSDictionary+FRMutableDeepCopy.h"

NSMutableDictionary *dixDataMutable = [[dixResponse objectForKey:@"data"] mutableDeepCopy];
```

After that you can update nested dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

try using this method

```
+ (instancetype)dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType> *)dict;
```

for example

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:oldDict];
```

Edit:
Do something like this

```
NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:oldDict];
[newDict setObject:@"Don" forKey:@"Name"];
[dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
```

Comment: i add my responce to array : arrayGlobal = [Response objectForKey:@"data"] ;

Comment: in my case i have index inside index. How can i replace is in inside index?

Comment: that is different thn OP!

Comment: NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[[arrayGlobal valueForKey:[arrayAllColumn objectAtIndex:0]] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:oldDict];
        [newDict setObject:@"12" forKey:@"question_ans"];
        [[[[arrayGlobal valueForKey:[arrayAllColumn objectAtIndex:0]] objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];

Giving error

Comment: -[__NSDictionaryM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector s

Comment: That says you're trying to replace object at index of array but the object is not an array its a mutable dictionary.

Comment: i guess `[[[[arrayGlobal valueForKey:[arrayAllColumn objectAtIndex:0]] objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
` this is a bad way, find a better solution as your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change the value of `question_ans` & `question_ans_comments`

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{ \"data\": { \"My_Tool_Box\": { \"Visual Check\": [ { \"que_cat_id\": \"1\", \"question_id\": \"1\", \"question_name\": \"Power leads\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } }, { \"que_cat_id\": \"1\", \"question_id\": \"2\", \"question_name\": \"Power\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } }, { \"que_cat_id\": \"1\", \"question_id\": \"3\", \"question_name\": \"Rcd is operational\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } }, { \"que_cat_id\": \"1\", \"question_id\": \"4\", \"question_name\": \"ase to avoid damage\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } }, { \"que_cat_id\": \"1\", \"question_id\": \"5\", \"question_name\": \"Safety guards if fitted to machine ARE OPERATIONAL AND ARE NOT DAMAGED\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } }, { \"que_cat_id\": \"1\", \"question_id\": \"6\", \"question_name\": \"ase to avoid damage\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } }, { \"que_cat_id\": \"1\", \"question_id\": \"7\", \"question_name\": \"ase to avoid damage\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } } ], \"Operational checks\": [ { \"que_cat_id\": \"2\", \"question_id\": \"8\", \"question_name\": \"ase to avoid damage\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } }, { \"que_cat_id\": \"2\", \"question_id\": \"9\", \"question_name\": \"ase to avoid damage\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } }, { \"que_cat_id\": \"2\", \"question_id\": \"10\", \"question_name\": \"ase to avoid damage\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } } ], \"Operating instructions\": [ { \"que_cat_id\": \"3\", \"question_id\": \"11\", \"question_name\": \"ase to avoid damage\", \"question_ans\": \"\", \"question_ans_comments\": \"\", \"question_options\": { \"1\": \"Yes\", \"2\": \"No\", \"3\": \"N/A\", \"4\": \"Comment\" } } ] } }, \"status\": \"success\", \"message\": \"Question Listing\" }";


NSData* data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSMutableDictionary *oldDic = [[[[dic objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"My_Tool_Box"] objectForKey:@"Visual Check"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"oldDic :: %@",oldDic);

[oldDic setObject:@"iOS Dev Answer" forKey:@"question_ans"];
[oldDic setObject:@"iOS Dev Comments" forKey:@"question_ans_comments"];

NSLog(@"dic :: %@",dic);
```

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:` unless you can explain why KVC is explicitly needed in this case. Can you?

Answer (score 0):

**The response which you get from the server is static.** So its come in **NSDictionary**. You need to alloc your own **NSMutableDictionary** and you have add all value into it.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dicYourData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:PASS_YOUR_RESPONSE_DIRECTORY];
```

Now you can use **dicYourData** anywhere and make it updatable.